# datepicker not showing calendar in IE11

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datapicker

I'm currently having some troubles with datepicker in IE11.
When I click on my textbox it works at least so far that an "x" is displayed on the right end of the textbox to delete its content. BUT the calendar itself is not shown.

When I tried to use textmode="DATE" instead of the jquery datapicker it resulted in the same end result.
I'm using a master / content layout and the jquery import is on the master page.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<br /><br /><br />
```

---

```
<script type="text/html">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= DisplayFromDateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        $("#<%= DisplayToDateTextBox.ClientID   %>").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<div>
    Welche Tage sollen angezeigt werden:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DisplayFromDateTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
    Bis
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DisplayToDateTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="DisplayButton" OnClick="DisplayButton_Click" Text="Anzeigen"/>
</div>

<asp:ListBox ID="JournalListBox" runat="server" Height="531px" Width="593px"></asp:ListBox>
```

In the master page I include jquery this way:

Edit: When I click into the text field (first one) the effect is as shown in the image below:
[image]

Update: When I removed the redundant parts of the ready function as proposed in the comments I made some erros. After correcting them I got a .js error when executing ready:   `$("#MainContent_DisplayFromDateTextBox").datepicker();` brings the error that the object or method does not support datepicker. This final problem was caused due to interference of an automatically created scriptreference to jquery which caused the manual include of jquery to malfunction.

Comment: which Jquery version are you using in your code?

Comment: @vibs2006 3.3.1

Comment: for IE 11 it is recommended to use JQuery 1.12. Can you try the code again with Jquery 1.12 and Jquery UI js related to that code version?

Comment: @vibs2006 tested it with 1.12.1 jquery and jquery-ui 1.12.1.  Same effect there

Comment: this 2 is the same, u just need either 1 `$(document).ready(function () {` and `$(function () {`

Comment: @Se0ng11 yeah can drop the innter $(function). will remove the redundancy tnx

Comment: Did you include the necessary jQuery CSS files in your HTML?

Comment: @HappyAnt which ones would that be?

Comment: Just one file: jquery-ui.css, should be in the zip if you downloaded jQuery. Or here: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: @HappyAnt I used nuget to download it (interestingly no .css that gets downloaded by it) ah correction there are a few .css in  a subfolder. including a datepicker.css

Comment: Well, then try adding a style tag to your html with the link I posted above as src and see what happens... (Or use the css files you just found ;) )

Comment: are you seeing any errors in your browser console when the pages loads? Also try to replace `type="text/html"` with `type="text/javascript"` and remove the extra `);` inside your `document.ready` function.

Comment: @GaganDeep replaced but no effect.  Ah when I replaced the redundant parts of the ready function I made some errors. Corrected them now I'm getting a new error message (updating the question).

Comment: do you mean you don't want the `hour:min:sec` part of the date in the textbox??

Comment: i don't see any error message in the screenshot you posted in the question.

Comment: @GaganDeep that was only to show how the screen looked. I found out what the "new" error was. Scriptreference to jquery was already included automatically and interfered with my manual includes. Case is now solved fully

Comment: ok great.. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try for this in this way

**1. Master Page**

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. Default.aspx**

```html
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        Welche Tage sollen angezeigt werden:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DisplayFromDateTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
        Bis
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DisplayToDateTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="DisplayButton" Text="Anzeigen" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= DisplayFromDateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
            $("#<%= DisplayToDateTextBox.ClientID   %>").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

I Hope this will help you @Thomas.

Comment: Good attempt but sadly no effect :/    Updated the question so that the exact happening is shown as screenshot and also put the .css line into it.

Comment: Corrected an error from when I removed the duplicate / redundant code I had as was proposed in a few comments. Now I'm getting an error message (pout it under update in the question).

Comment: @Thomas , I which sestion you have added jquery ?

Comment: yes. found the problem. ASp.Net automatically hat a scriptreference to jquery included...which interfered with the jquery manual include. In the end I made a scriptreference to jquery and jquery.ui.combined and it worked then :)

Comment: It's great @Thomas :). If you think my answer was helpful then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

HTML: Added the attribute CssClass on the from and to textboxes:

```
 <div>
        Welche Tage sollen angezeigt werden:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DisplayFromDateTextBox" CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
        Bis
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DisplayToDateTextBox" CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="DisplayButton" OnClick="DisplayButton_Click" Text="Anzeigen" />
    </div>
```

Change the script code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var currentDate = new Date();

        $("input.datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            maxDate: 0,
            changeYear: true
        });

        $("#<%= DisplayFromDateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker("setDate", currentDate).datepicker('show');
        $("#<%= DisplayToDateTextBox.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: the extra ) was a cut error (due to a comment from Se0ng I eliminated a redundant code part but overlooked the ")".

Comment: Jquery UI css is also required to make the calendar attractive. Checkout more option's here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: jquery ui css I have included now correctly (had some troubles with the nuget package). Additionally Corrected an error from when I removed the duplicate / redundant code I had as was proposed in a few comments. Now I'm getting an error message (pout it under update in the question).